# django download file link

Tags: django, python-3.x

Can someone help me. I have `FileField()` for upload files like .doc or .pdf from admin panel. I can upload file like admin but I can't download this file like user. The download link does not work?

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    """Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book)."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Введите краткое содержание книги")
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text="Выберите жанр книги")
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    specifications = models.FileField(upload_to='router_specifications')
```

**book_detail.html**

```
<p><strong>Download:</strong><a href="{{ book.specifications.url }}">Download</a></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some information about your error and your tries to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT settings variables and add view to serve the media files?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: what about "This is not suitable for production use"?

Comment: Ineed, this is not for production. Usually in production you use nginx/apache and serve the file using them.

Comment: I did: MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media_root")      is it right?

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in locallibrary.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    catalog/
    ^static/(?P<path>.*)$
    accounts/

The current path, media/router_specifications/Iktisodiyot.pdf, didn't match any of these.

Comment: Did you add 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
to your urls.py

Comment: It's work! thanx. and what you think can I use MEDIA_ROOT in production for university library? is it bad practise?